# Connection timeout Play JPA using Executor Service

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a play 2.4 application and I've setup a tool to run in scheduled executor like this (in Global):

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
Bot myBot = new Bot();
ScheduledFuture<?> sched =  scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(myBot, 2, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

And ultimately it makes a call to a DAO to fetch some data to see if the work it is doing is a duplicate:

```
try{
            results = JPA.withTransaction(() -> {

                String queryStr = "select id from BotSearch bs "
                             + "where bs.headerText=:headerText";

                Query query = JPA.em().createQuery(queryStr);
                query.setParameter("headerText", title);

                return query.getResultList();
            }

        );  


        }catch(Throwable t){
            Logger.error("Failed to issue bot query ",t);
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When it makes that call the connection times out every time. I can make that DB call in other parts of the application and other DB calls and they succeed every time.

Is there a thread local issue with the entity manager that would prevent it from making calls as part of a scheduled task? Or is there any thing else that may be causing this issue? It only fails inside the scheduled tasks.

The exception is:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: Timeout after 30028ms of waiting for a connection.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:227) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.getConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:182) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.9.Final.jar:4.3.9.Final]
javax.persistence.QueryTimeoutException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1725)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1771)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:64)
    at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:133)
    at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:80)
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:127)
    at com.myproject.dao.BotSearchDAO.isDup(BotSearchDAO.java:34)
    at com.myproject.bots.alert.Bot.run(WSJBot.java:131)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: can you show your code where `callable/runable` is used?

Comment: @Patrick Happy to provide more but not sure what you're looking for. That code above is where it is scheduled and the DB call runs in the run() method of the task.

Comment: I was looking for where you receive the result of the thread. Something like `sched.get()`

Comment: @Patrick The thread doesn't return anything. It wakes up, does some work, and tries to do some db operations. That db code above is the second thing it does after it finds some data.

Comment: Ok. To point out if the issue is regarding the thread or jpa/enitiy manager, can you show your Bot.class. I suppose there is the runnable implementation.

Comment: @Joan note http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314488/how-to-deal-with-serial-tag-only-edits-from-sub-2k-users

Comment: @Floern It doesn't matter we are all blocked to 1k reputation. What matters is that we don't have to scan all tags foreach damn version: playframework-2.1 playframework-2.2 playframework-2.3...

Answer (score 0):

I will make a guess on this one.

I think this has to do with that when you use your own thread you bypass the JPA context that is managed by play.

There are probably a few ways to get around it but [`Job` seems to be the preferred one](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/jobs). There is an example of *Scheduled Jobs* in the end.

There is also the [`JPAPlugin`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/api/play/db/jpa/JPAPlugin.html) to force initialization of the JPA context and starts a transaction.

```
JPAPlugin.startTx(false);
// Do your stuff
JPAPlugin.endTx(false);
```

Similar stackoverflow questions

- [JPA and Threads in play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795086/jpa-and-threads-in-play-framework)
- [Play Framework: Manually open JPA context for Spring RabbitMQ listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808378/play-framework-manually-open-jpa-context-for-spring-rabbitmq-listener)